# Javascript is unable to stop page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, view

I have a sign-up page having proper validation's every place. But whenever i click "Sign-Up" on a blank form. It shows the validation, but gets loaded. I want to stop the loading. How's that possible.

I am primarily checking on chrome, where i checked on settings, whether javascript is disabled or not, but it is enabled.

it's happening in an .cshtml page.

Feel free to ask any question

Comment: Its because after validation also you are trying to submit form.. Please post your code..

Comment: Why not post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using validation, you must place the if condition.

For example:

```js
a = validate('something');

(validate - is the validation
  function, but you can have another name of
  function)

if (!a) {
  return false;
} else {
  --your form submit here--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First may b you used `<button type="submit">` ..This will forcefully submit the form i.e. load the page you have to use `<input type="button">` and then write validation as @llkin suggest Use `return false` to stop load the page

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myFormId" onsubmit="myFunction()" novalidate>

</form>

myFunction(){
//you logic goes here
document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
}
```

use novalidate attribute to disable to default validation of form and you can use custom function to validate on submit. In myFunction() define your custom logic to validate and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

DO not use button type submit.
Onclick call a function where you have to validate all fields and return true/false.
Call that function in your validation function check the value if true submit form.

May be this helps you.